# Maven an java.io.scanner(System.in)

Tags: testing, maven, input

I'm running into issues with my project. When running in Netbeans it seems to work fine with user interaction. However when I run using mvn test it does not. I see the command line menu but I am not prompted to make a selection. When I force terminate the project, I get an error about No Line Found.

Any Ideas? I'm stumped.

The line that isn't working is essentially:

```
System.out.print("1) Print String\n"
+ "0) Exit\n"
+ "Enter Selection: ");
String line = (new java.util.Scanner(System.in)).nextLine();
```

I see the output Similar to this:

```
1) Print String
0) Exit
```

But I don't see "Enter Selection: " and it doesn't prompt for the String input. I terminate and get "No Line Found" though after I cancel the execution I see the whole string int he "Test Results window".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's abnormal for unit tests to pause for user interaction. I wouldn't be surprised if it acts strangely. I expect the testing libraries don't really anticipate this sort of thing.

Comment: Although you say it's abnormal, is there a way to allow the user to interact with this? Or is there a better practice? I would assume since the application is required to run under mvn test for the assignment, and the assignment requires user interaction that it would need to allow interaction in at least some form.

Comment: 1) Make the user interaction layer as thin as possible. That makes it easy to test everything else. 2) Be inventive. You say the assignment requires user interaction, but you can prefab some inputs for the tests. If System.in is your input mechanism, that's just a stream. Build your classes to be able to use any arbitrary stream for input. Then you can provide any kind of stream you want during testing, thus eliminating the need for manual interaction.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, one should not interact with user while performing JUnit tests. Tests should be designed to operate automatically and continuously. If you want to test underlying code with two separate values, two tests should be implemented and call each the underlying code with their own value. This should cover for the two options offered to your user.